How to switch off automatic wheel building in databricks asset bundle python wheel task
I have the following databricks asset bundle job defintion:
        - task_key: test-model-from-wheel
          python_wheel_task:
            entry_point: run # Entry point of the wheel
            package_name: myservice # must match the name of your package in toml or setup.py
            parameters: ["-a", "test_run", "-m", "model_test"]
          libraries:
            # By default we just include the .whl file generated for the hdf package in the previous make builds
            - whl: ../../${var.wheel-file-path}
          new_cluster:
            instance_pool_id: ${var.instance-pool-id}
            spark_version: 15.4.x-scala2.12
            autoscale:
              min_workers: 1
              max_workers: 4

however, when i run in the command line databricks bundle deploy -t dev it will ignore my existing already build wheel file specified in - whl: mywheelfile which i have build before in a separate make command. It will just autodetect that there is a buildable python command and build again.
How to switch this off?
i tried to put absolute paths, i was already playing around with command line flags. Sadly the asset bundles docs are quite sparse on these patterns atm.

Ok, there does not seem to be an official solution but in the global databricks.yml of the bundle: when i add there an artifact statement indicating that i want to build with make it will use that and still build, however build in the config i have in mind. thats a workable solution atm. e.g. one could put there a script that skips building.
this goes at the highest level of the databricks.yml:
artifacts:
  default:
    type: whl
    build: make build-and-test-wheel
    path: .

